# deleting a pattern from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"a","b"},{"c","d","prq"},{"e","f","wxy *1"},{"g","h","wxy *2"}}
```

I would like to delete all elements that have an "*", to make:

```
res = {{"a","b"},{"c","d","prq"},{"e","f"},{"g","h"}}
```

This would seem to be a job for StringContainsQ and DeleteCases, but am not sure how to do this.  Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[lis, _String?(StringContainsQ["*"]), All]
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d", "prq"}, {"e", "f"}, {"g", "h"}}
> ```

```
lis /. _String?(StringContainsQ@"*") :> Nothing
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d", "prq"}, {"e", "f"}, {"g", "h"}}
> ```

```
Select[StringFreeQ["*"]] /@ lis
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d", "prq"}, {"e", "f"}, {"g", "h"}}
> ```

```
Pick[lis, StringFreeQ["*"] /@ lis]
```

> ```
> {{"a", "b"}, {"c", "d", "prq"}, {"e", "f"}, {"g", "h"}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks @kglr for the different options, will do some timing tests on larger data sets.